# VBA to change the name of the Activex button

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am not sure, even if this is possible. I would like to change the named of the button when clicked.

I have Active X button that will enable cells on the sheet when clicked. Name of the button "Enable Sheet".

Once he enables, he should see a button "Disable Sheet". Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your button is named after "CommandButton1":

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object
        .Caption = IIf(.Caption = "Enable Sheet", "Disable Sheet", "Enable Sheet")
    End With
End Sub
```

edited after OP's comments

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    With Me.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object
        .Caption = IIf(.Caption = "Enable", "Disable", "Enable")
        Range("E13:E14").Locked = .Caption = "Enable"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. I am sure we can change the name of the button. So when button name is displayed as "Disable" and when user clicks on it. It shoud go the disable function and when it displays "Enable" it will enable the function. Correct?

Comment: Basically I use this code to enable /disbale cells Range("E13:E14").Locked = False and Range("E13:E14").Locked = False

Comment: no need to change the name of the button. just change its `caption` and have its code handler act accordingly

Comment: @user3598756..wow!! amazing. Absolutely amazing. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @user3598756Just to make it user friendly. Is it possible to to grey-out the sheet and only highlight "enable" button, so that it would easy for user to know that he needs to click on button...Is that possible?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm sure the greying out thing is possible, although it's a new issue and should you get stuck with it post a new question. While for the current one since I answered your _original_ question, please accept my answer. thank you

Comment: Besides accepting it, you may also want to upvote my answer should you find it useful.

Comment: Certainly!! I have posted a new question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357603). Please help me on the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127101/discussion-between-sady-and-user3598756).

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you can attach to the ActiveX object, you can try something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Enable"
End Sub
```

In general, for ActiveX Objects, you can change the displayed text using the `.Caption` property.